# Trying to emulate Bressenham's Line Algorithm in Lua but it returns an error(CC: Tweaked)

Tags: lua, line, computercraft

I am trying to make a module for CC: Tweaked that as one of its features uses Bressenham's Line Algorithm to draw a line between 2 points on a monitor. However when I run my program I get this error:

```
pixels.lua:24: attempt to index local 'y1' (a number value)
```

Please note that I got this code from a youtube video and it is possible that I wrote something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
local pixels = {}
 
function pixels.drawPixel(x, y, monitor, color)
    monitor.setCursorPos(x, y)
    monitor.setBackgroundColor(color)
    monitor.write(" ")
end
 
function pixels.fillScreen(color)
    x, y = monitor.getSize()
    for j = 1,y,1
    do
        for i = 1,x,1
         do
            pixels.drawPixel(i,j,monitor,color)
        end
    end
end
 
function pixels.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, monitor, color)
    error = 0
    slope = y2 - y1 / x2 - x1
    
    pixels.drawPixel(x1, y1. monitor, color)
    
    for x = x1,x2,1
    do
        error = error + slope
        if error >= 0.5
        then
            y = y1 + 1
            error = error - 1
        end
        
        pixels.drawPixel(x,y,monitor,color)
    end 
    
end
 
return pixels
```

Comment: y1. You used as period instead of a comma.

Comment: all you needed to do is to thoroughly read through line 24...

Answer (score 0):

Line 24:
`pixels.drawPixel(x1, y1. monitor, color)`

As stated in the comments above, y1 has a period instead of a comma after it, telling Lua to look for a value from y1.monitor when y1 is not a table. Thus, "Attempted to index a number".

(Also, you do not have to declare your incrementor number with your for loops if the number is 1)

Comment: and so, question officially answered :P